Problem with associated token account of a mint account which initialized using Token2022
I have a mint account created from this script which utilizes Token2022 Program: Solana playground..
Now I am trying to create an ATA(Associated token account) by passing the mint account and user's public key.
 const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress( mintKeypair.publicKey, payer.publicKey );
When I log this, I get a newly created key. Now to initialize this key into an actual account on Solana blockchain I am using this code snippet:

But it is not getting initialized, also I have a question, since the mint account is initialized by Token2022 program, does the ATA also include token2022 as a seed?
As in getAssociatedTokenAddress() it is hardcoded for token program to be TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID


could you share the error logs

When deriving an ATA for token-2022, you also need to provide the token-2022 program id. Try doing:
const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
  mintKeypair.publicKey,
  payer.publicKey,
  false, // the default
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);

See the source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d1c03cc6164ebdeebef19190de28b7a71f4e4cb6/token/js/src/state/mint.ts#L162

Yes, I was able to do this, through this method.
Thankyou!!
